# Kruger vs Serengeti

Tags: africa, safari

### Background

---

I am looking to book a safari for my fiancé and I next June.

It will be our first time going on a safari and we were wondering if anyone had any thoughts or experiences with either of the two locations.

We are planning on spending anywhere between `3-7 days` on safari and another 7 days relaxing in possibly Mauritius or Zanzibar (depending on which safari we go on).

### Location

- Serengeti or
- Kruger national parks.

---

### Influencing Factors

---

### 1. Animals

We are looking for the best animal viewing/experience in terms of:

- Diversity of animals
- Proximity to the animals

### 2. Budget

Our maximum would be around `€800` per day for safari access and accommodation.

### 3. Weather

- At this time of year, which park would have a greater visibility/proximity to the animals.
- Is the growth of the vegetation anything to consider that would impact our visibility/proximity to the animals.

### 4. Accommodation

As luxurious a large possible as long as we can stay within our daily budget.

Comment: Can you explain how you define 'best animal viewing'? Most? Most diverse? Or perhaps easy access to the parks is a criterion? Or perhaps cost?

Comment: @MastaBaba I changed the entire structure of the question

Comment: Excellent. Voted to reopen.

Comment: How many are in your group and what kind of accommodation would you like? Minimal tented camp or luxury lodge? Some preliminary info about KNP: weather in June is typically cool and very dry, which means the vegetation is not so attractive, but makes it easier to spot animals as there is less foliage in the way, and animals must gather at watering holes to drink. The minimum cost for foreigners to enter the park is about 15€ per adult per day, about the same per guided walk or drive.

Comment: @Max I have updated the post with more information. Thanks

Comment: I visited Kruger and stayed in the park-run lodges inside.  It cost closer to 800 euro per *week*.  :)  It sounds like you're looking for private game reserves though--is that right?  I would suggest that three days is not enough--if you can stick to the longer end of your time budget you will be rewarded.

Comment: This comparison raises some interesting points (I used it in writing my [partial] answer) http://www.jenmansafaris.com/head-to-head-serengeti-vs-kruger-travel/

Answer (score 1):

In my limited experience, all game-viewing is a matter of luck. You will almost certainly not see everything you hoped to see, wherever you go: the wild is wild, and many animals are doing their best not to be seen. So no place can guarantee you will see what you want to see, but you can have a fantastic experience anyway. Suggestion: buy a birding guide. Kruger has some absolutely beautiful birds (I'm sure Serengeti does too), and many an hour of looking in vain for lion or zebra has been rescued by spotting some of them.

I have visited Kruger National Park (KNP) in June or July, but never the Serengeti. This answer will therefore be based on a mix of experience and online info.

June is the cool-and-dry season in both KNP (average of 11mm of rain; 6-26°C) and Serengeti (31 mm; 15-26°C). This means the vegetation is not so attractive, but makes it easier to spot game as there is less foliage in the way, and animals must gather at watering holes to drink.

In Kruger National Park your budget should easily cover anything you want to do (the best accommodation in the park, plenty of guided walks and drives, and eating in restaurants). I don't have much experience of what the higher-end accommodation is like, but it's probably not five-star. However there are private game reserves nearby which offer much more expensive experiences. You may wish to visit both (it's also common to stay in a lodge in a private game reserve, and visit KNP on some days).

Perhaps the best-known attraction of the Serengeti is the Great Migration of wildebeest and other grazers. According to https://www.expertafrica.com/tanzania/info/serengeti-wildebeest-migration this pauses in June; the most spectacular time is in July.

One big difference, apparently is that KNP is *accessible*: it's a relatively short drive from Johannesburg, and South African schools will be on holiday until the 24th of June. This means the park may be quite busy in places (the southern part much more than the north).

But Kruger is also more accessible in a different sense: if you rent a car, you can tour Kruger pretty much independently. While I recommend taking guided drives and walks as well, you can just take your car and drive in any direction, move randomly across the park, and end the day at the same or another camp. (You must return to camp between dusk and dawn, though, unless you're on a guided drive). Apparently Serengeti is much less accessible in this way.